# When we click on dynamic link then null data comes

Tags: flutter, mobile

when we click on any shared dynamic link then application opens but get null data...

[image: here is screenshot of get initial link...]

[image: for getting initial link i called at initState...]

i checked Receive Firebase Dynamic Links in a Flutter app https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/dynamic-links/receive/  but i can't find any solution of it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to add `setState` which is necessary to rebuild the widget tree. Try this :

```
if(data!=null){
  setState((){
     final Uri deeplink= data.link;
     print('Link ====> $deeplink');
          });
        }
```